# How to locate TextBox programmatically in WPf 2010

Tags: wpf, location

I created a TextBox in WPF 2010 programmatically:

```
TextBox tb= new TextBox();
tb.MaximumSize=new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
```

How to define a location this TextBox programmatically on the Form?

```
tb.Margin = System....Drawing(0, 0, 0, 0); -  does not work.
```

Comment: WPF doesn't care about `System.Drawing`. I suggest you remove the reference to that. Also, I Strongly recommend you look at [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/). You shouldn't be creating UI Elements in code in WPF to begin with.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as `MaximumSize` in WPF.

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as WPF 2010. There's WPF versions corresponding to each .NET release from 3.0 to 4.5, and there's Visual Studio versions 2008, 2010, and 2012.

Comment: There is "MaximumSize" and it works okay. I just cannot locate TextBox programmatically

Comment: @StepUp, NO, there is no `MaximumSize` in WPF `TextBox`, and if there was there is no way you could apply a `System.Drwing.Size` to it. I think you have created a Winforms TextBox by mistake by dragging in winforms references into your WPF application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF example

```
TextBox textBox=new TextBox();
textBox.Width = 100;
textBox.Height = 100;
textBox.Margin=new Thickness(20,200,100,100);

Content.Children.Add(textBox);
```

where `Content` is `StackPanel`

Winforms example

```
TextBox textBox=new TextBox();
textBox.Location=new Point(100,100);
this.Controls.Add(textBox);
```

Comment: Can you post your xaml and you method where you try to create TextBox?

Comment: Also post please your using section. May be you try to create Windows.Forms TextBox instaed of WPF TextBox.

Comment: textBox.Margin=new Thickness(20,200,100,100); the error of converting

Comment: Yeah. I create winforms.textbox as I need to create windorms.textbox programmatically in WPF 2010

Comment: Do you want paste it to WPF page/window or on Windows.Forms form?

Answer (score 0):

What container are you putting the textbox into? If you're putting it into a DockPanel, you need to do something like

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
</DockPanel
```

so that WPF knows where the margins apply.

Comment: I created programmatically in ".cs" file. Not in xaml

Comment: @StepUp, If your using WPF you SHOULD be using the xaml

Comment: Yeah, I know but my situation is demand to create textbox programmatically